How to create and use multiple standalone vue apps in one html page (Vue2 + Django)
Im kind off new to vue and I'm trying to implement a vue + vuetify + vuex frontend in my already half written django application, I want the vue applications to connect independently of each other in different divs of html page
At the moment, with this connection:
<div class="tab-content" id="settings-tab-content">
    <script type="application/json" id="initial-data">
        { "is_superuser": {{ is_superuser|lower }} }
    </script>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="groups-tab-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="groups-tab">
        <div id="userGroups"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="structure-tab-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="structure-tab">
        <div id="app"></div>
    </div>
</div>

import Vue from 'vue'
import clinicStructure from './clinicStructure.vue'
import userGroups from './userGroups.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(clinicStructure)
}).$mount('#app')

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(userGroups)
}).$mount('#userGroups')

Components and building with this
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --dest=../../static/builds/prod",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service build --dest=../../static/builds/dev --mode=development --watch"

works fine but modal windows from one app open in another (in the one that is mounted first)
So, how can I make a separate vue component connect to a specific div without affecting other components
p.s. I can't make one entry point for frontend and then process paths through vue router, I need django to give html with connected vue components

"modal windows from one element open in another" - it's unclear what's the meaning of this.  Since you use Vue CLI (the question doesn't mention this explicitly), you can use "pages" for subapps, but the result is expected to be the same. Different new Vue are enough for the apps to be separated

@EstusFlask There are several navigation tabs (bootstrap) each tab has its own vue application, but if I am on the first tab and I click some button that brings up a modal window, it opens in an inactive tab, for which another (second) vue application is responsible

You didn't mention bootstrap at all, and it can be used in different ways with vue. This totally depends on the implementation.  It's unknown how the modals are implemented, the question mentions vuetify but that's all. Consider providing a way to reproduce
